# GOOGLE FORM - How to specify the name of the folder I want to upload files in Google Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am currently using this google scripts application below to upload files received from the google form into my drive but it only classifies the items into the form responses' unique ID. I have little to no experience in tech but can follow instructions so please please bear with me.

I would like to know how can I manipulate this line of code so that I can make a new folder (based one answer in the gform) for every entry.

I am guessing it is the "SubfolderName" portion that needs to be editted.

https://www.labnol.org/file-uploads-folder-google-forms-201226

See google script below:

```
const PARENT_FOLDER_ID = "<<Folder ID here>>";

const initialize = () => {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
};

const onFormSubmit = ({ response } = {}) => {
  try {
    // Get a list of all files uploaded with the response
    const files = response
      .getItemResponses()
      // We are only interested in File Upload type of questions
      .filter(
        (itemResponse) =>
          itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD"
      )
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
      // The response includes the file ids in an array that we can flatten
      .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

    if (files.length > 0) {
      // Each form response has a unique Id
      const subfolderName = response.getId();
      const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
      const subfolder = parentFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);
      files.forEach((fileId) => {
        // Move each file into the custom folder
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder);
      });
    }
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f);
  }
};
```

Comment: I thought that in your situation, it is required to know the detail of `based one answer in the gform`. Because I think that in order to achieve your goal, `subfolderName` is required to be set as you say. In this case, it is required to retrieve the value from `getItemResponses()`. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your form. So I thought that it is required to know the detail of `based one answer in the gform`. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Do you want the folder name to be set from a specific question in the form?

Comment: Put some console.log in your code and see what is in each variable. When does the log stop showing what you expect. Is there an error message?

Comment: Do you want the folder name to be set from a specific question in the form? – Rafa Guillermo Jan 11 at 12:28 -- Yes Rafa, I would want to do this